# Should I build front end files during deployment on production or use compiled files?

Tags: deployment, build, continuous-integration, frontend, gulp

During development I often run gulp build script to build html and js files. It is quick action. But to install all needed infrastructure I shoud install npm with a lot of modules, bower, gulp and a lot other tools. It took me more then a half of hour to install all this tools in test server.

So should I use the same approach to deploy my code to production server or it's better to build all files locally and upload them during general deployment process?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using npm for package management you should run npm install on production server because there can be different packages for different systems.

This makes you independent of the fact that the machine to build must always be exactly the same as the machine in production.